# How to return to ios static library from another app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I would like to create a static library and this library download some data from server and if my other app is installed on the phone open it, after the user do something in my other app i would like to return to the library.
How can i do this?
I can open my other app from my library but i cant return to my library.

Comment: What does it matter if this functionality is implemented in a static library?  None as far as I can see.

Comment: Because this library just should help other developers to integrate my system into their app

Comment: It's not relevant to the question though.

Comment: I need this library because i got a lot of email from developers because they are silly and cant implement two rest api request and create some model...

Comment: Im not sure i understand you correct... doesn't Facebook do something like this? By opening one app from another and when doing so sending a callback scheme for that app to run when done to open the original app again.

Comment: Peter yes, something like what facebook do, but i would like this in a library. So open app -> start my library -> library start another app -> another app return to the library -> library return to the main app

Comment: A app started by another app will always get (and only) get a call to the App Delegate. If you want your desired behaviour you will have to require the application developer of the consuming app to call your code from the app delegate when the app you open returns. No biggie tho.

Comment: Yes i tried that inherit the main app appdelegate from the appdelegate of the library, but the url scheme is in the main app and it not return to the library. Or it should be work? I did something wrong?